# Quick Sort in Java by passing values from 3 files?

Tags: algorithm, command-line-arguments, quicksort

My sorting algorithm is working fine, but in the output, I want to display values from all the 3 files passed through command line argument.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Qsort {

    static long startTime;
    static long endTime;
    static long totalTime;
    static ArrayList<String> allInputFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Long> allDuration = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> allSize = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Double> allValues = new ArrayList<Double>();

    /**
     * Calling readFileFromArguments, quickSort & saveConsoleOutputToFile
     * methods
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // To calculate the start time from start of the execution
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Reading all the argument from command line
        // which are file names 'input1.txt', 'input2.txt', 'input3.txt'
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String file = args[i];
            allInputFiles.add(file);

            // Calling the function to read input file
            double[] unsortedArray = Qsort.readFileFromArguments(allInputFiles.get(i));

            // Calling the function to perform quick sort on unsorted array by
            // passing unsorted array n both end points
            double[] sortedArray = Qsort.quickSortAlgo(unsortedArray, 0, unsortedArray.length - 1);

            // Calling the function to save the sorted array into text file
            Qsort.saveConsoleOutputToFile(sortedArray);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method reads the file by creating an input stream and return the
     * double array to main method
     * 
     * @param file
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static double[] readFileFromArguments(String file) throws IOException {
        // Creating an Input Stream to read the file using FileInputStream and
        // BufferedReader
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Reading multiple lines from the input stream
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = null;
        while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }

        // Splitting the list through ';' delimiter
        String strArray[] = stringBuffer.toString().split(";");

        // adding all the elements of input file in arraylist
        allSize.add(strArray.length);

        // Creating an integer array of length of input array
        double unsortedArray[] = new double[strArray.length];

        // Storing the values into integer array
        for (int i = 0; i < unsortedArray.length; i++) {
            unsortedArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(strArray[i]);
        }

        // return the unsorted array to main method
        return unsortedArray;
    }

    /**
     * This method sorts the 'unsorted array' by using quick sort logic
     * 
     * @param arr,
     *            leftVal, rightVal
     * @return
     */
    public static double[] quickSortAlgo(double[] arr, int leftVal, int rightVal) {

        // picking up a pivot value in the middle of our array
        int pivotIn = leftVal + (rightVal - leftVal) / 2;
        double pivotVal = arr[pivotIn];

        // looping around pivot on both sides while checking to see if
        // left value is less than pivot and right value is greater than the
        // pivot
        int i = leftVal, j = rightVal;
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr[i] < pivotVal) {
                i++;
            }
            while (arr[j] > pivotVal) {
                j--;
            }
            // swapping values on both sides of pivot
            if (i <= j) {
                double temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
            // recursively calling the method by checking left value
            if (leftVal < i) {
                quickSortAlgo(arr, leftVal, j);
            }
            // recursively calling the method by checking right value
            if (rightVal > i) {
                quickSortAlgo(arr, i, rightVal);
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }

    /**
     * This method saves the console output into "answer.txt" file with the help
     * of PrintStream
     * 
     * @param sortedArray
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void saveConsoleOutputToFile(double sortedArray[]) throws IOException {

        // Creating a File object that represents the file to be written
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new File("answer.txt"));

        // Assign printStream to output stream
        System.setOut(printStream);

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                System.out.print("; "); // splitting the values using delimiter '; '
            }
            if (sortedArray[i] % 1 == 0) { // checking if the array is decimal or integer
                int intArray[] = new int[sortedArray.length];
                for (int j = 0; j < intArray.length; j++)
                    intArray[j] = (int) sortedArray[j]; // creating the integer sorted array
                System.out.print(intArray[i]); // display the integer sorted array
            } else
                System.out.print(sortedArray[i]); // display the decimal sorted array
        }

        System.out.println();

        // calculating total running time of the algorithm based on input file
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        allDuration.add(totalTime);

        // to print the performance analysis table with input file details
        System.out.println("\nPerformance Analysis:");
        System.out.println("Input File(s)\t Size\t Sorting Time (in milliseconds)");
        for (int i = 0; i < allInputFiles.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(allInputFiles.get(i) + "\t" + allSize.get(i) + "\t" + allDuration.get(i));
        }
    }}
```

Output:

> -4; 0; 0.5; 1; 2; 2; 2; 2; 2; 2.3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3; 3.5; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4; 4.4; 5; 5; 5; 5; 5; 5; 5.5; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6.6; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7;
>   7; 10.9; 12.6; 22; 22; 33; 35; 44.4; 44.55; 45; 45; 45; 46; 53; 55;
>   55; 56.667; 62; 65.66; 67.77; 111; 223.23; 246; 455; 622; 1000.9

Performance Analysis:

```
Input File(s)        Size        Sorting Time (in milliseconds)

input1.txt     
10  5
input2.txt     
56  168
input3.txt     
68  175
```

Above output is printing only the values of the 3rd file.

[image: image description]

Comment: (Don't do `new StringBuffer("")`. Declare "variables" using interfaces, not classes.) A method `readFile…()` can read but *one* file true to its name. You are using `Stream` methods, anyway: use a [SequenceInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#constructor.summary) if you want a combined input. You are overwriting the results - either keep the output open, or use [`new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(…, true))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-).

Comment: @greybeard .. Thanks! it works. But now the performance analysis table is printing thrice. How to overcome that?

Comment: It's working thanks, I solved the issue!